# R session aborts when running bclust function from bclust package in RStudio

Tags: r, session, abort

This forum always comes to my rescue whenever I have a problem with running codes in r. It's that first time that I am making  a post to ask for help.

I am frusterated while trying to figure out why my r session aborts every single time when I try to use fucntion 'bclust' from bclust package. The function works fine with the dataset 'gaelle' that comes with the package, however, it doesn't work with my own dataset that has 146 metabolites in columns and 1715 observations in rows. I have tried updating rstudio, using a smaller dataset, resintalling r and a few more tricks after reading answers to similar problems on this platform. Nothing seems to work. I am a newbie with R and stackoverflow and don't know exactly which information will be needed to answer the question. I am providing complete code that I am running to get the results and link to a subset of my dataset to reproduce the issue.

Link to the dataset:

https://github.com/Sidra85/sidra/commit/9e7a6a335e24c09b12e7af5dc3721808aad32166

```
median_center <- function(x) {apply(x, 2, function(y) y - median(y))}
centered_dat <- median_center(dat)
mc.dat <- meancss(centered_dat, rep.id=1:nrow(centered_dat))
optimfunc <- function(theta) {
  -loglikelihood(x.mean=mc.dat$mean, x.css=mc.dat$css, repno=mc.dat$repno, transformed.par=theta)
}
transpar <- optim(rep(0, 6), optimfunc, method="BFGS")$par
bclust(centered_dat, transformed.par=transpar)
```

I will be immensely obliged to have received any kind of help to get out of this problem.

Comment: What happens when you run your code in a clean R terminal (i.e. don't run the code from within RStudio but from within the R application itself)?

Comment: Package `bclust`was archived 7 years ago and the help page `help('bclust')` says in its Details section that *"The C-stack of the system may overflow if you have a large dataset. You may need to adjust the stack before running R using your operation system command line."* I haven't been able to reproduce the error, your code ran fine.

Comment: @Mauris Evers I am sorry I never ran codes in R terminal. If I understand correctly you are treferring to what I know as R script. I ran my codes in new clean R script window and problem persists.

Comment: @Rui Barrads that means there is hope. I looked up how to increase/adjust C-stack size in r but guess I am too naive to understand the solutions. Could you please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Probably that's one of the reasons why [`bclust` was removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bclust/index.html).

Comment: @jay.sf yeah. Intsalling bclust was quite an ordeal on its own. It kept giving me a hard time until I updated rtools.

Comment: @Maurits Evers I previously misunderstood you I guess. I ran my codes again in R 'Terminal' and the problem is still tere. The code runs just fine with gaelle dataset again. However, with my own dataset, the r session is not aborted but terminal window seems to be not operating any longer.

Comment: @SidraRashid I see. Considering Rui & jay.sf's comments, this all seems to suggest that the issue is with `bclust` (and R rather than RStudio), which, given `bclust`'s status of having been archived for 7 years, is probably no surprise. Unfortunately I'm afraid there is little you can do here. Perhaps try with an older version of R, and/or manually increase the stack (as per Rui's comment).

Comment: @Maurtis Evers I contacted  one of the developers of the package .According to him 'package has memory leakage and may not work for large data' and  'If the number of rows * columns exceeds 2500 do not expect that the package work' but the package was used successfully by certain researchers who had 183*163 dataset.  Rui Barrads was able to run the code just fine on my subset of the data but it doesn't work on my machine. So I guess the problem is complex. I have given up on the idea of employing Bayesian hierchical clustering altogether. I really appreciate everyone's feedback here.